# How to keep the maven structure when creating source-jar

Tags: maven, maven-source-plugin

I am using the maven-source-plugin to pack the sources of the project.
Normally you get all from the main/java and main/resources packed together into one root.

What I want is to keep the project structure in the final -source.jar - 
like `src/main/java/**`, `src/main/resources/**` and the test part too.

I tried the *includes* configuration which did not help

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <id>attach-sources</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
        </goals>
            <configuration>
                <includes>src/main/**, src/resources/**</includes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The error I get is

```
[INFO] Failed to configure plugin parameters for: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:2.3

(found static expression: 'src/main/**, src/resources/**' which may act as a default value).

Cause: Cannot assign configuration entry 'includes' to 'class [Ljava.lang.String;' from 'src/main/**, src/resources/**', which is of type class java.lang.String
```

Is it really the "found static expression" error or is the configuration no correct?
Or is there another way to achieve this?

---

### Edit

So when changing the POM as in the hint from @carlspring the error is gone, but the result is that neither source nor resource files are in the resulting sources.jar

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
        <includes>
        <include>src/main/**</include>
        <include>src/test/**</include>
        </includes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Maybe the clue is in the description of the *includes* option:

> List of files to include. Specified as fileset patterns which are relative to the input directory whose contents is being packaged into the JAR.

Which means if the input directory for *jar-no-fork* is src/main/java|resources then my question must be answered **NO WAY**

Comment: Have you tried to build without the `<includes>...</includes>` ?

Comment: Sure I did, but the result is what I do not want, resources and code in parallel not separated.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the `<includes/>` incorrectly. This is not a comma-separated list. Each entry should be defined as it's own `<include/>`. Try it like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <id>attach-sources</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
        </goals>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>src/main/**</include>
                    <include>src/resources/**</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Furthermore, I would actually recommend you use the `maven-assembly-plugin` instead and create the sources with it, as it would be much easier, in my opinion. Have a look [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/multimodule/module-source-inclusion-simple.html).

Comment: Although this answer is useful regarding the wrong include format it does not help with the concrete question.
The results using the include parameters are such that no source files are in the generated sources.jar, only the POM and META.INF